# Change direction on overflowing dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple dropdown menu. The navigation is floated right inside a 500px container. If I its the last (the one most to the right) that is active the dropdown will overflow the container. How would I limit it so it wont overflow but just float right instead.
[image: example]

[JS Fiddle](http://goo.gl/ubBVJB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try width this code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pUNN/1/)

```
.children {
    line-height: 48px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want them in the left side unless they overflow the container

Comment: then you will have to use jquery. Have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it