# How to make submenu of dropdown to open on the left side or right side automatically depending upon room available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**The submenu shows to the right and is off of the screen when there is plenty of room to pop open on the left. how can i implement the feature that allows submenu to appears to the left rather than right by first checking to see where the menu should appear**

Here are the images to show what i exactly mean. (This is typical windows right-click on desktop taken for example)

[image: Submenu on left when there is no room on right]

***In this image, submenu is opening on left knowing that there is no room on right side.***

[image: Submenu on right When there is room on right]

***In this image, submenu is opening on left knowing that there is room on left side.***

I want to implement feature like this.

So, how i can achieve this?
I tried tweaking my CSS 
with this

```
.sf-menu > li:last-child > ul ul {
  left: auto; // reset the default positioning
  right: 100%; // this makes the submenu fly out to the left
}
```

with [Supposition Plugin written by Joel Birch](https://gist.github.com/joeldbirch/5371649)

this solves it. but i can't use this plugin in my work.

is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Plain CSS can't do this. You have to know the width of your submenu, calculate the available space and then add a corresponding CSS class via JavaScript.

Comment: Alright. that was helpful. but how should i calculate the available space. that depends on browser windows size. any lead or help ?

Comment: You should provide some code to make us see what you got already and we will improve it together.

Comment: I used above listed plugin. check it out.

Comment: The plugin seems to work. So where's the problem?

Comment: I can't use this plugin in my work. i have to make my own kind of function.

Comment: So here we are back to the point where we need some of YOUR code to proceed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11525189/1004312

Comment: @chm-software.com - i can't show my code. it's private repository. i am sorry. i was asking for hints.