# How can I add Class to a Sub Menu that Overflows to Offscreen?

Tags: javascript

I want to add Class using Javascript to check if sub menu overflows to offscreen and fix it if it does. I don't know how to do it but `Gridlove` theme has that feature. It is made with below jQuery codes but I want to do it using Pure `Javascript`:

```
$('.gridlove-main-nav').on('mouseenter', 'li', function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('body').width() < $(document).width()) {
        $(this).find('ul').addClass('gridlove-rev');
    }
});
```

How can I do what I want using Pure JS codes for the same function?

Website: https://miyavliyo.com/ or https://wisekitten.com/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood very well what you mean but your jQuery can be translated like so:

```
const gridloveMainNav = document.querySelector('.gridlove-main-nav');

gridloveMainNav.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
if (e.target.closest('body').offsetWidth < document.offsetWidth) {
e.target.closest('ul').classList.add('gridlove-rev');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the answer to the question asked here as well. [Dropdown menu does go out off browser screen - bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185294/dropdown-menu-does-go-out-off-browser-screen-bootstrap-4)

The theme I mentioned and the associated code do this successfully. But I couldn't do it with the code you wrote, I couldn't run it.

[image: The place to apply the transaction.]